# Cmake not finding Phonon

Tags: 11.10, qt, phonon

I'm working on a Qt application that uses Phonon and has CMake as it's build system. When I try to configure the application I get the following configure output:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11 - found
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN - not found.
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found.
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found.
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:91 (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find Qt4 (missing: QT_PHONON_LIBRARY) (found suitable version
  "4.7.4", required is "4.4.3")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:252 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1162 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:21 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

I know my CMakeLists.txt isn't the problem because it works fine on other machines. Also, I have libphonon-dev installed. Anyone know what the problem is? I feel like I may not have the right phonon package installed. There are so many different ones in the repository. Which one is the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess for what ever reasons CMake just didn't want to find libphonon.so which I determined was located in /usr/lib/. So after manually setting QT_PHONON_LIBRARY_RELEASE to /usr/lib/libphonon.so everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put this in your CMakeLists.txt file?

```
SET( QT_USE_PHONON TRUE )
```